# How to change manufacturer data

Tags: magento-1.9, manufacturer

I'm using **Magento V1.9.3** and I have a question about manufacturer field.

I have inserted a lot of **manufacturers**, but some of them are wrong and I need to change some words or delete it and create a new one

> example: from > *MICROSOFT SPAIN* to > *Microsoft-Spain*

I tried doing this, direct from **admin panel** but I can't save this changes :

> Magento Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manufacturer

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why can't you save the changes? Do you get an error? What is the problem?

Comment: @Gustavo Did you increase the value for `max_input_vars`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to save your updates to the values of an attribute, you likely need to increase the value for `max_input_vars`. Take a look at your exception log in var/log/ to see if there are any errors pointing to this issue.

If so, increase the value for `max_input_vars` in **php.ini** configuration file and see if that helps.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your prompt answer. I will check and return

Comment: @Gustavo Did increasing the value for max_input_vars resolve your issue?

Comment: Dear Aaron, i looked for php.ini file and a cannot find that. It's inside php folder and I have no access to that folder, I'm asking my agency to take care of this asap.   Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gustavo, was your host able to resolve the issue by increasing the value for `max_input_vars`?